# Prevent browser scroll to hash on document ready, then animate slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my script.
It was working perfectly until last week, when my client talked about it.
My website has some links with an hash added to scroll smoothly to id when page is loaded. Now  it doesn't scroll smoothly anymore. I did check my variables, and it gets the hash has id (e.g.  #content) and also the height of the  header nav.
I can't find the problem.

Here's the script:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    //bind to scroll function
    $(document).scroll( function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        //var hashName = hash.substring(1, hash.length);
        var element;

        //if element has this id then scroll to it
        if ($(hash).length !== 0) {
            element = $(hash);
        }

        //if we have a target then go to it
        if (element !== undefined) {
            window.scrollTo(0);
        }
        //unbind the scroll event
        $(document).unbind("scroll");
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: ($(element).offset().top - $('header nav ul').height()) }, 500);
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Still wasn't able to fix the script.. does anybody have an idea why it doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Native scrollers dont work nice. Handling different browsers and mobile devices is realy difficult. Use iScroll my friend http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5 .. it works like a charm and comes with a lot of features!!!

Comment: After checking this plugin, it seems to have nice features. But there's a lot more plugins focused on scroll.
But i'd rather just find a way to fix this script, instead of adding another plugin to the website, and having more http requests.
Thanks for the quick answer.